# VLC : How to RTMP Stream to WOWZA with RTMP Authentication?

Tags: authentication, streaming, vlc, rtmp, wowza

I have my Wowza with protected RTMP Channel. The authentication is OK while using softwares like, FMLE / WireCast / etc, of course.

- But how to do with VLC?